# Who can find the most efficient path counting algorithm?

Tags: combinatorics

**This question was put on hold as off-topic because:

"...it appears to be a mathematics problem, as opposed to a mathematical puzzle." However, it is not a mathematics problem. There is no known mathematical solution. As one of the commenters already realized, the puzzle is to find a more efficient counting algorithm (likely using some coding language).**

The goal is to find a counting algorithm that is better than simply recursing through every possibility, which will take a very long time. My implementation does it in just under 30 minutes, but I am very sure that other people can do it faster.

Below is a grid of the flags of the 70 countries with the largest population, in order from left to right, top to bottom. Both the upper left cell (the blue star) and the lower left cell (the green smiley) aren't flags. The flags don't serve any purpose for the question, other than to make the grid prettier, and drop some knowledge about population size by country.

[image: Grid of Flags for the 70 most populous Countries]

You must find the total number of paths that meet all of the following conditions:

Each path must
1. start in the blue star cell
2. end in the green smiley cell
3. visit each of the 70 flags exactly one time
4. move up, down, left, or right, but not diagonally

Here are a couple examples of valid paths:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe this is an unsolved problem in combinatorics.

Comment: Yay, I'm gonna be famous! haha

Comment: Related (but unanswered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249499/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-the-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-through-a-grid

Comment: There would be at least 100k results I think. Or around 10k possible routes

Comment: @PythonMaster There are many more than that. I need an exact number.

Comment: I said about! I am innocent!

Comment: haha. fair enough.

Comment: it might take a super computer a year or two for this. Call Jon Skeet!

Comment: My C# solution did it in around 8 hours if I remember correctly. I'd be surprised if Skeet and many others couldn't do it way faster, since I did no study of tree trimming, but only optimized it by trial and error. I will re-run it again now to verify this comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21873/discussion-between-pythonmaster-and-jlee).

Comment: I can affirm that there are less than [467,260,456,608](https://oeis.org/A003763). If anybody goes to Idaho State University or Walla Walla University, they can go check out a [book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Enumeration_of_Hamiltonian_Cycles_and_Pa.html?id=z65xuAAACAAJ) that might hold the answer

Comment: This would be a puzzle if you added a constraint (or multiple constraints) to the path. Top-of-my-head examples: Only move to a flag •...which shares a color; •... of a country with a smaller population; •...whose country name shares two letters. Of course, you'd then have to guarantee that there _was_ such a path.

Comment: @Josh Caswell  Both good points

Comment: Correction: My C# solution found the answer it 29 minutes, 4.78 seconds, running on an i-7

Comment: This is an interesting Project Euler-style puzzle. The goal is to find a more efficient path-counting algorithm than the naive one.

Comment: Is there *any* reason why the grid uses flags?? If not, I'd edit it down to a simple square. When I first saw this "puzzle", I thought it could hold potential - If there is some logical restriction in the flags (or associated countries.) *Just* paths is, well, *boring*.  -1 (but no close-vote) from me.

Comment: @BmyGuest If it is so difficult to just count paths, it would likely be far more difficult to count only certain paths. So, since you (and many others) would consider just paths to be boring, then I have no incentive to remove the pretty flags.

Comment: Flagged for mod: Migrate to Math SE

Comment: I vote to reopen.  Make it clear that the goal is to find a way to count the paths, not just count the paths.

Comment: @Len Thank you for the link. If you look carefully, the problem I presented here is much more intense, because you can move up, down, left, and right, and must cover all 72 squares with each valid path, but in the other problem, you can move only up and right, and need not (and can not) cover all squares (or path segments).

Comment: [Very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248317/what-is-a-better-algorithm-for-finding-routes-that-traverse-all-vertices-in-a-gr), with top answer stating how this is the Hamiltonian Path Problem